# why is an array variable not considered set if it is assigned `()`?

Tags: bash, variable, array

bash manual says:

> A parameter is an entity that stores values
>
> A variable is a parameter denoted by a name.
>
> A parameter is set if it has been assigned a value.
>
> An array variable is considered set if a subscript has been assigned a value.

Is an array variable a variable and a parameter?

If yes, why is an array variable not  considered set if it is assigned `()`?

```
$ ar=()
$ echo ${ar-This is a new value}
This is a new value
```

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How do I check if a variable exists in an 'if' statement?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/246703)

Answer (score 4):

In `bash`, like in `ksh`, where `$var` is an array, `$var` is actually short for `${var[0]}`.

So in:

```
var=([1]=whatever [2]=blah)
```

`${var+set}` would not expand to `set`, and `[[ -v var ]]` would return false, because `$var` has no element of indice 0 (note that in `bash`, like in `ksh`, but contrary to most other shells and languages, arrays are sparse arrays, or associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers).

In `bash` (at least since 4.3), when you declare a variable as array with:

```
typeset -a var
```

`var` is initially unset. It's not even set to an empty list. In `4.3`, `typeset -p var` would return an error. In 4.2 and before it would output:

```
declare -a a='()'
```

(as if declaring the array assigned an empty list like it does in `zsh`)

In 4.4, it outputs:

```
declare -a var
```

So, since 4.3, an unset (but declared) array is different from an array that is assigned an empty list.

Still, it's difficult programmatically to differentiate between both. But in practice, the distinction is not very useful. Most likely, what you want to know is how many elements are in the array:

```
((${#array[@]})) || echo array has no element
```

See `zsh`, `rc`, `fish` and `yash` for shells with better array designs.

Comment: Thanks. `${var+set}` treats `var` as `var[0]`. Does   `$(parameter+word` expect `parameter` to be a nonarray variable? If not, how can I specify `parameter` to represent an array?

Comment: In 4.4, when run `unset var` and `declare -i var`, then run `declare -p var`. Does it output error such as `bash: declare: var: not found` or `declare -i var`? I would like to see if it treats array differently from other types. I have 4.3 only.

Comment: That is not the correct way to test an array: `${var[@]+set}` is (`:+` fails on ksh93). What you used only test index 0.

Comment: In bash: *typeset -p var would return an error* only in 4.3, It was correct before and became correct with 4.4 again.

Comment: @Tim, it outputs `declare -i var`.

Comment: @Arrow, thanks. Though that's not the full story. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

The construct `${var-foo}` expands to `foo` if `var` is unset *or null*.
An empty array is exactly that.

As you quote:

> An array variable is considered set if a subscript has been assigned a value.

The example you site (`ar=()`) does not assign a value to any subscripts.

Comment: But `${var-foo}` doesn't check whether the array is set but whether the element of indice 0 (beware it's not necessarily the same as the first element as `bash` arrays are sparse) is set.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to test for a whole array is:

```
[[ ${ar[@]+set} == set ]] && echo "array has a value may be a null"
```

What you wrote is the test for the value at index 0. This two are equivalent:

```
${ar+set}
${ar[0]+set}
```

But both will only test whether the array at index zero is set or not, not the whole array, which I assume is what you meant.

But, to your question: Why is an array unset if asigned ()?

Because you have **not** asigned any value, not even the null, to any array index.
To get some index to be set (and consequently the array) you need something like:

```
$ declare -a ar=([3]="value")
```

Or even:

```
$ declare -a ar=([3]="")
```

zsh (even in sh or ksh emulation) is the only one of all shells tested (as usual, the special one) that declare an array as set with:

```
$ unset ar; typeset -a ar=(); echo $(typeset -p ar) ${ar[@]+set}
```

---

Question from comments:

> Thanks. Can ar[@] be replaced with ar[*] here? Are they array variables?

No, an `"${ar[*]}"` is the string concatenation of all array values.

However, in this specific expansion: "${ar[*]+set}" both are equivalent.

From the manual (at Arrays):

> If subscript is @ or *, the word expands to all members of name.

Comment: Thanks. Can `ar[@]` be replaced with `ar[*]` here? Are they array variables?

Comment: @Tim Answer edited.

Comment: Good point about `${a[@]+set}` (see also `[[ -v a[@] ]]` (in bash, not in ksh)). About `a=(); echo "${a[@]+set}"`, `yash` (another one of the shells with the better array designs) also outputs `set`. In `ksh93`, `a=(); echo "${a+set}"`, which declares an empty compound variable, also returns `set` which makes it even less consistent there. `bash` just copied `ksh`.

Comment: No, in this case, bash does not act as ksh93 (in none version). With `a=(); echo "${a+set}"` ksh outputs `set` (and that is incorrect), bash don't (and that is correct). The difference between ksh and bash is still present with `a=(); echo "${a[@]+set}"`. All shells correctly report `set` with `a=(""); echo "${a[@]+set}"`, so, it is just a matter of correcting a bug of ksh with no index set (not even to null).

Comment: @Arrow, in `ksh93`, `a=()` doesn't declare an array but a compound variable. It is set because it is not unset, it's been assigned a value (the empty list). Arrays receive a special treatment probably for backward compatibility. In ksh88, you'd set arrays with `set -A a x y` very similarly to Bourne's setting of the `$@` array with `set x y`. There was no `typeset -a`, `set -A a` was the same as `unset a`. That's still the case in `ksh93` though it has `typeset -a` which allows to _stick_ an array attribute to a variable. If you don't use typeset, `a=(1 2); a=($())` still unsets the variable.

Comment: Good grief !!. Why `a=()` and `a=('')` mean completely different syntax?. Try `ksh -c 'a=(); typeset -p a'`. There is no solution: The reuse of already defined syntax will *always* be error friendly. The syntax to define arrays `a=([1]="11")` was available for long. When ksh re-purposed such syntax to compound variables it just created a source of parsing mistakes. Just analyze `ksh -c 'typeset -a a=("11");a.x=3;a.y=7;typeset -p a;echo ${a..}'` It prints `typeset -a a=((x=3;y=7.=11))`. What is the double `((` supposed to mean?. How could we understand the string `y=7.=11` ?. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Beside, and appart of that, that the test for an array `${a[@]}` prints `set` is a mistake if what was defined was a Compount variable `a=()`. No array called "a" exists, what do exist is the compount variable *label* called "a". Those are very diferent things. So, I still believe the test is failing in ksh. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @Arrow, I agree it's unfortunate that `a=()` doesn't make `a` an array, but note that in ksh88, arrays were not really a different type from scalars. scalars are just arrays with only the 0 indice set. In ksh88, `a=1`, `set -A a 1`, `a[0]=1` were equivalent, and for the most part, it's still the same in `ksh93`. You can do `unset a` instead of `a=()`, that won't make `a` less of an array. Note that `bash` also uses the same syntax for different types of variables (why does `a=()` not declare an empty associative array?).

Comment: If an scalar use the same memory structures of an array is not a concern for the user. For the user an array should be diferent than an scalar. If not ; the expression of some idea in some syntax gets lost, and the user gets confused. But what was being compared was a Compound variable to an Array variable, ksh confuses them. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Maybe because it is the "least surprising" action for `a=()` ?. The shell try its best to make an array, an indexed array. Only if **told** to do so, it creates an Associative array. No guessing, no divining, just simple rules. @StéphaneChazelas